# react-router-dom Link does reload site

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I started a project, which is in essence built like this:

```
App.js
-> ListView.js
-> SingleEntryView.js
  -> (variable views using react router dom)
  -> NavComponent.js to switch between those views
```

My URLs: `www.my-site.com/entry/<ID>/<view>` and `www.my-site.com/list`

At `www.my-site.com/entries` there is a list of all entries,
at `www.my-site.com/entry/<ID>/<view>` you can see some details, which depends on the `<view>`.

Furthermore, the navigation is in essence there to switch between the views. Therefore the navigation does need the `<ID>` to switch e.g. from `www.my-site.com/entry/<ID>/details` to `www.my-site.com/entry/<ID>/history`.

---

**My approach**

... starts by using a Router at the App.js component:

```
<Route exact path='/list/' component={ListView} />
<Route exact path='/entry/:id/:view' component={SingleEntryView} />
```

Then, in `SingleEntryView.js` I have access to the `this.props.match.id` which I can pass to the `NavComponent` to create RouterDom-Links to the different views.

I pass the match like this to the Navigation:

```
<NavComponent id={this.props.match.params.id} />
```

My Navigation is then using Router Links to navigate to the different views, like this (using material ui):

```
<BottomNavigationAction
component={Link}
to={`/entries/${this.props.id}/details`}
label="details"
/>
```

Furthermore, I created another Route to decide which View is displayed beneath the Navigation, I did that like this in `SingleEntryView.js`:

```
<Route path={`/entry/:id/detail`} component={DetailView}/>
<Route path={`/entry/:id/history`} component={HistoryView}/>
<Route path={`/entry/:id/foobar`} component={FooBarView}/>
```

---

**My problem**

... is, whenever I click on one of those Links in the NavBar, then the View is completely reloaded - including componentDidMount (all the remote contents are reloaded).
How can I prevent that? I thought Link is exactly there to prevent that**?

P.S.: I am aware that this might not be the cleanest solution - I am a react beginner, so if you have a better idea let me know :D

P.P.S.: I simplified everything a bit, if there is a typo somewhere: forgive me please :D

Comment: Are you using `BrowserRouter` ?

Comment: Oh wait.. you mean.. when you go from one view to another the contents are reloaded because it's in `componentDidMount` of the view you pass to Route's `component` prop? Yes this is default behaviour. Link does nothing to prevent that. If you want to check if a resource has already been fetched you need to cache that information somewhere *above* your component like a global store or above your Route definitions

Comment: @azium: Yes, right - I am using <BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter> once at the App Component. I don't know if I understood correctly: Is it default behaviour that "ComponentDidMount" is called again when the component is loaded again by Route?

Comment: yes that's right. the component passed to Route is only mounted when the path matches. If it's mounted and the path changes and no longer matches the component is unmounted. There are various ways of triggering an initial fetch when your component mounts and then keeps that data somewhere outside of the component that gets unmounted like in the app component.

Comment: @azium: If I would use an address like `entry?id=<id>&view=<view>, then it should work - right? because it is still the same address

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to do in that case. are you not still loading different components based on the url?